# Am I able to be sued for patent infringement as an sales agent?

Tags: liability

If I sell a product in the US as a US resident sales agent on behalf of an EU seller of a product they manufacture in the EU that subsequently breaches a US patent can I be sued?

Comment: This might be better asked on the Law SE site: https://law.stackexchange.com

Comment: Imho that's a patent law question @EricS

Comment: @DonQuiKong I wasn't suggesting it was off topic, just that there might be good answers to be had on Law SE.

Answer (score 2):

Anyone who made, used, sold, offered to sell, or imported a patented product infringed the patent.

So, yes.